# method keeps old parameters while variable has changed

Tags: java

In my code I have an actionperformed, inside it I call a method with parameters the problem is when I call the method.when the actionperformed is executed for the first time it takes the right parameters, then when the actionperformed is executed for the second time variables used in the method header have changed, but the method keeps old parameters, I can't find how to fix it.

here is the method code:

```
    protected int searchString(int j, String str, String[][] B) {
    int exist = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < B[B.length - 1].length; i++) {
            if (B[j][i].equals(str)) {
                exist = i;
                search = true;
                System.out.println(B[j][i]);
            }
        }
    System.out.println(search);
    return exist;

}
```

and here is where I call it:

```
chooser.submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                System.out.println(filePath);
                A = fl.fileReader(filePath);
                System.out.println(search);
            if (chooser.neTypeCbBox.getSelectedItem().equals("BSC/RNC")) {
                if (chooser.operationCbBox.getSelectedItem().equals(
                        "PS throughput usage (SW\\HW)")) {

                    if (chooser.bscTypeCbBox.getSelectedItem()
                            .equals("G U")) {

                        searchString(
                                4,
                                "Average Total Throughout of UL and DL PS Services for RNC (kbit/s)",
                                A);
                    } else if (chooser.bscTypeCbBox.getSelectedItem()
                            .equals("U O")) {
                        searchString(4,
                                "VS.PSLoad.MaxThruput.RNC (kbit/s)", A);
                    }
                    else if (chooser.operationCbBox.getSelectedItem().equals(
                        "DPU usage")) {
                    if (chooser.bscTypeCbBox.getSelectedItem()
                            .equals("G U")) {
                        searchString(4,
                                "AR9760:Average CPU Usage of the DPU (%)",
                                A);
                    } else if (chooser.bscTypeCbBox.getSelectedItem()
                            .equals("U O")) {
                        searchString(4, "VS.DPU.CPULOAD.MEAN (%)", A);
                        System.out.println(search);
                    }
                    if (search) {
                        chooser.setVisible(false);
                        welcome.rightPanel
                                .add(dpuUsage, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                        welcome.rightPanel.remove(chooser);
                        dpuUsage.setVisible(true);
                        search = false;
                    }
                }
}
}
 } catch (IOException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        e1.getLocalizedMessage(), "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the values from the actionPerformed method? If so, with what result?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure you read the http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Also, try to improve your code formatting. Read more at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan thanks for answering,but I didn't understand what u say.

Comment: If a called method does not see the values you expect, the first thing to ask is what do the values look like in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way the method would keep the same parameters. what's probably happening is that the first condition is always evaluated to true, which leads to the call of the method with the parameters in the underlying block.

Comment: Adding logging and/or println calls immediately before each call to `searchString` would clarify which call is happening, as well as what the caller is passing to it.

Comment: well, I did that. The A variable is changed and I've checked immediatly before the searchString call it is changed but the  searchString still takes the old value of A in parameter.

Comment: from your comment i gather you expect A to change, but i can't see how that is supposed to happen. if possible add the code for fl declaration and filePath content. especially filePath content since it's where the data comes from.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I get in my console:

```
D:\Downloads\UO DPU usage(03112015 1540)_20150311_154036.xls
D:\Downloads\UO DPU usage(03112015 1540)_20150311_154036.xls
reading..
D:\Downloads\UO DPU usage(03112015 1540)_20150311_154036.xls
false
VS.DPU.CPULOAD.MEAN (%)
true
true
D:\Downloads\UO CPU usage(03112015 1541)_20150311_154121.xls
D:\Downloads\UO CPU usage(03112015 1541)_20150311_154121.xls
reading..
D:\Downloads\UO CPU usage(03112015 1541)_20150311_154121.xls
false
VS.DPU.CPULOAD.MEAN (%)
true
true
```

the file path changes so A does too, but when I call searchString it affects true to the variable search while the String "VS.DPU.CPULOAD.MEAN (%)" is not contained in the second file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't reset variable `search` back to false after the first match? At least that seems to be the case from the code segment you provided.

Comment: I did, this why it displays false then it's back true again,  I dsipaly the String "VS.DPU.CPULOAD.MEAN (%)" from inside the method it self, the second file doesn't coutain it, but it shows again.